# How to turn off logging from docx4j-ImportXHTML

Tags: docx4j, flying-saucer

When I use docx4j-ImportXHTML, I get a lot of logs.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

---

```
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 1 column 52 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 2.0
2 warnings, no errors were found!
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 1 column 651 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 2.0
2 warnings, no errors were found!

org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: Loaded document in ~90ms
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: TIME: parse stylesheets  241ms
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.match INFO:: media = print
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.match INFO:: Matcher created with 137 selectors
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: Loaded document in ~3ms
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.load INFO:: TIME: parse stylesheets  0ms
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.match INFO:: media = print
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.match INFO:: Matcher created with 137 selectors
```

How to turn that off? It's generating huge amounts of log entries on our appserver.

Answer (score 1):

org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer is org.xhtmlrenderer repackaged and extended for docx support; see https://github.com/plutext/flyingsaucer

flyingsaucer has its own logging system, independent of and different from docx4j (which uses slf4j).

You configure flyingsaucer's logging using xr.util-logging: 
 https://github.com/plutext/flyingsaucer/blob/master/src/conf/xhtmlrenderer.conf#L56

That file is typically included in your inside your docx4j-ImportXHTML jar: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/pom.xml#L255

So check inside that jar for the conf file, and alter it there.

For example, xr.util-logging.loggingEnabled=false

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new config file with properties you want to override and reference the new file under an environment variable.

Create a new conf file and put this in your app resources
i.e.

```
resources/conf/xr-overrides.conf
```

Add this property in your xr-overrides.conf file to disable logging

```
xr.util-logging.loggingEnabled = false
```

Add this property to your env vars to enable conf override with the lookup location

```
xr.conf=classpath:conf/xr-overrides.conf
```

Or

```
static {
    System.setProperty("xr.conf","classpath:conf/xhtmlrenderer.conf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of manipulating the jar, you can add the following line to your code:

`XRLog.setLoggingEnabled(false);`

It has to be a call before your initial call to the ImportXHTML library, but when it's loaded (first I tried to add it in main(), but it didn't work until I put it in the constructor of my class using the xhtml-import.

Bye
Jan-Patrick

Answer (score 0):

It helped to copy xhtmlrenderer.conf from jar and put in project resources with modified line:

```
xr.util-logging.loggingEnabled = true
```